# How can I use Runge-Kutta4 to solve this orbit in polar coordinates?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, computational-physics, algorithms

I want to simulate a simple orbit of a planet moving around a star which is fixed in position. I have formulated the ODEs for this problem using Lagrangian Mechanics and have found the equations of motion for a 2D orbit in polar coordinates.

I have found these to be:

$$ \ddot r - r \dot \theta^2 = \frac{-GM}{r^2}$$

and:

$$r\ddot\theta+2\dot r\dot \theta = 0.$$

I would like some help formulating the problem in a way in which I can solve for $(r,\theta)$ using the RK4 method (I am aware this method is non-symplectic but I want to use this method first and will probably update to use velocity vertlet or something later on)

I have never used RK4 before to solve for two variables simultaneously and this is where my confusion in how to proceed arises.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for codes rather than physics

Comment: @KyleKanos I disagree. The OP didn't ask for code. He only needed the concept how to transform second-order ODEs to a first-order ODE, as required for Runge-Kutta.

Comment: Solving the two-body problem using cartesian coordinates in an inertial frame and without using relative coodinates is by far the most instructive way to do it. My students learn a lot of mechanics doing that way. Velocity Verlet algoritm is recommended, not oly because it is symplectic, which is important for a problem where angular momentum should be conserved, but also because it is very simple to implement and very efficient (one evaluation of force per step).

Comment: @ThomasFritsch then he should have opened any book on numerical methods where this surely is discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use numerical simulation program , you have to transformed the differential  equations  to first order differential equations (1)

$$\vec{\dot{y}}=\vec{f}(\vec{y},t)\tag 1$$

Example:

$$\ddot{r}-r\,\dot{\theta}=-\frac{GM}{r^2}\tag 2$$

$$r\ddot{\theta}+2\,\dot{r}\dot{\theta}=0\tag 3$$

new variables :

$y_1=\dot{r}$

$y_2={r}$

$y_3=\dot{\theta}$

$y_4={\theta}$

equation (2):

$$\dot{y}_1-y_2\,y_3=-\frac{G M}{y_2^2}$$

equation (3):

$$\dot{y}_3\,y_2+2\,y_1\,y_3=0$$

thus:

$$\vec{\dot{y}}=\vec{f}(\vec{y})$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  \dot{y}_1 \\
   \dot{y}_2\\
  \dot{y}_3 \\
   \dot{y}_4\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
  -\frac{G M}{y_2^2}+y_2\,y_3 \\
   y_1\\
  -\frac{2\,y_1\,y_3}{y_2}\\
  y_3
\end{bmatrix}$$